# Trying to get CSS grid layout correct

Tags: css, grid-layout

I am designing my own website using HTML and CSS. I have decided to use a grid as follows:

```css
/* Style the grid container */

.item1 {
  grid-area: logo;
}

.item2 {
  grid-area: cta;
}

.item3 {
  grid-area: menu;
}

.item4 {
  grid-area: spacer;
}

.item5 {
  grid-area: left;
}

.item6 {
  grid-area: right;
}

.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: 'logo cta cta' 'menu menu menu' 'spacer  spacer spacer' 'left right right';
  grid-gap: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.grid-container>div {
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}

.item1 img {
  min-width: 200px;
}


/* Responsive layout - makes the three columns stack on top of each other instead of next to each other */

@media (max-width: 600px) {
  .grid-container {
    grid-template-areas: 'logo' 'cta' 'menu' 'spacer' 'left' 'right';
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="item1">
    <img src="Images/DN signatur    es/dn_gold.png" style="width:25%" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="item2">
    <p>dermot at dermotnolan dot ie</p>
  </div>
  <div class="item3">
    <div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
      <a class="mnu active" href="#home">Home</a>
      <a class="mnu" href="#about">About me</a>
      <a class="mnu" href="#gallery">Gallery</a>
      <a class="mnu" href="#imw">IMW</a>
      <a class="mnu" href="#blog">Blog</a>
      <a class="icon" href="javascript:void(0);" style="font-size:18px;" onclick="myFunction()">&#9776;</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item4">
    <br/>
  </div>
  <div class="item5">
    <h2>Column 1 in Myriad</h2>
    <h5>A heading in Consolas</h5>
  </div>
  <div class="item6">
    <h2>Column 1 in Myriad</h2>
    <h5>A heading in Consolas</h5>
    <h2>Column 1 in Myriad</h2>
    <h5>A heading in Consolas</h5>
    <h2>Column 1 in Myriad</h2>
    <h5>A heading in Consolas</h5>
  </div>

</div>
```

My issue is that it looks like this:

[image]

Where I am expecting the left-most items (logo, left) to be one-column wide...

I'm certain I'm missing something simple, if anyone can make suggestions I'd be grateful.

Thanks in advance,

Dermot

Comment: "... I am expecting the left-most items (logo, left) to be one-column wide". What do you mean exactly? Can you share an image of what you're after?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have forgotten to call your CSS file in the HTML document. you will need to call your CSS file in the head of your HTML file like the example below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link  type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"  href="/css/styles.css">
<title></title>
</head>

I have attached a picture of my output.[screenshot of the picture][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8LxGK.png
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually I had referenced my CSS - what you see above is simply an excerpt from the code.

However, I managed to find a good solution which works perfectly:

```
=================================================
grid elemnent styling copied from 
https://css-tricks.com/simple-named-grid-areas/#top-of-site
as well as W3Schools
=================================================
*/ 

/*HEADER area */
.gridheader {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  grid-template-columns: 300px 1fr  1fr;
  grid-template-areas: 
    'logo logo cta'
    'menu menu menu'
    'spacer spacer spacer';
}
/*MAIN area */
.gridcolumns {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr  1fr;
  grid-template-areas: 'left right right';
}
```